# CSS - How to make CSS class invalid for single element

Tags: html, css

I have a Wordpress website which contains a lot of pre-written CSS-code. One of the prewritten code-snippets looks like this:

```
input[type=url] {
    color: #666666;
    ... (a lot of other styling properties)
}
```

Now I wanted to create a design for a single page which contains an input field of type `url`.

`<input type="url" id="input_url" class="dtd-settings-element"></input>`

The problem is, that I want to style this input field completely on my own but the pre-written code is affecting that style. Is there a possibility to "deactivate" the pre-written CSS snippet for my new input field?

I know that I can overwrite all the attributes from the pre-written snippet in my `dtd-settings-element` class. But doing this for multiple elements would not be optimal.

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction :)

EDIT:

Last thing I tried was:
`input[type=url]:not(#input_url)`

Comment: Are you able to modify the pre-written rules directly? Or are they set in stone?

Comment: Hey DBS, the rules are set in stone. Can't change them :/

Comment: Unfortunately, if you can't change them, you will need to set the property differently in your more specific selector. CSS is an additive set of rules, once a rule is included in the file it can't be removed (programatically), only overridden.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unique id of the input field with `!important` to target that element and just apply whatever style you want...

```
#input_url {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: It is probably worth noting that they would also have to apply styling with `!important` to counteract any styling being applied by Wordpress that is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to override styling.

```
#input_url input[type=url] {
    color: #000;
    font-size: initial;
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to deactivate pre-written CSS in your terms. All the possibilities you have already mentioned:

- Override all class properties
- Modify original styles
- Change type attribute

However you can change tag from input to (for example) textarea.